# App Icon is not appearing while sharing post via firebase dynamic link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

I successfully created a Dynamic Link in Firebase to share posts. However, when I share the post, the app icon is not visible and instead, Firebase's icon is displayed. Everything works fine other than this. Can you help me resolve this issue? [see image here](https://ibb.co/yps6dp5)

```
func sharePostWithDynamicLinking() {
    guard let link = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/\(displayDataObject?.postId ?? 0)") else { return }
    let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "https://www.example.com"
    let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix)
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "") // here I have mentioned my app's Bundle ID
    
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "" // here I have mentioned my app's appStoreID
    linkBuilder?.iOSParameters?.minimumAppVersion = "1"
        
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = "Example of a Dynamic Link"
    linkBuilder?.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = "This link works whether the app is installed or not!"
        
    guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder?.url else { return }
    print("longDynamicLink --> \(longDynamicLink)")
    
    linkBuilder?.shorten { url, warnings, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Oh no! Got an error! \(error)")
            return
        }
        if let warnings = warnings {
            for warning in warnings {
                print("Warning: \(warning)")
            }
        }
        guard let url = url else { return }
        print("I have a short url to share! \(url.absoluteString)")
        
        self.shareItem(with: url)
    }
}

// Share dynamic link
func shareItem(with url: URL) {
    let activityView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
    if let topVC = UIApplication.topViewController() {
        topVC.present(activityView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the firebase official link, you can put image in socilMetaTagParameter

```
linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters.imageURL = "https://www.example.com/my-image.jpg"
```

check this link for further information

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/create?hl=es-419
[image]

Comment: I understand that point. But I have one question: When we share a post, does our app's logo automatically appear or do we need to pass it as shown in the documentation? In a video I saw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGrjUeJq0xs&t=1114s, the app's logo appeared automatically without being passed. Can you confirm if this is the case?